# Return array<custom class> from method

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Ok so I make a call to firebase and return children for the given location.

I then loop through the returned values and populate my custom class, i.e `description` and `id` this works, as I log the `options` to the console and I can see the entries.

Issue I have is trying to return the values from this method to my component as present the code looks like this:

```
 getIntent(): Promise<Array<Dropdown>> {

    const options: Dropdown[] = [];
    var d = this.af.database.list('/option1').subscribe(items => {
        items.forEach(item => {
            options.push({
                id: item.$key,
                description: item.$value
            })
            return false;
        });
    });

    return options;

}
```

On the return line its currently underlined with the following error:

`Type 'Dropdown[]' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Dropdown[]>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'Dropdown[]'.`

I've tried:

```
return options as Promise<Array<Dropdown>>;
```

But sadly that didn't work, can someone shed some light into how I go about getting this function to return the dropdown options.

Sidenote: currently using `angularfire2` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

getIntent(): Observable<Dropdown[]> {

  return this.af.database.list('/option1')
    .map(items => items
      .map(({$key, $value}) => ({
        id: $key,
        description: $value
      })
    );

}
```

You would then subscribe to this method in some component.

It is also worth noting that while your question suggests the use of a `class` called `Dropdown` we are not instantiating it. If `Dropdown` is indeed a declared as a `class`, it would be best to change it an `interface` so that it is not possible to accidentally perform an `instanceof` check that will always be false.

**before**

```
export class Dropdown {
  id: string; // maybe number?
  description: string;
}
```

**after**

```
export interface Dropdown {
  id: string; // maybe number?
  description: string;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the suggestion, however I'm getting the following error: `[ts]
Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Dropdown[]>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.`

Comment: That's not right, what type is returned by database.list? If it's already a promise, then a different approach is needed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your asking, I'm building an array of Dropdown class which consists of two fields description and Id.  hence the code in my original question.  I then want to return this back.  database.list? ???

Comment: Looking at the documentation it looks like it returns a FirebaseListObservable<T> so we don't want a promise at all.

Comment: Ok..... do you know what modifications I would need to do to the code you provided?

Comment: I I updated my answer based on the interface in the source code but it's possible I got something wrong

Comment: I had an error on `items =>
      .map` stating expression expected....